# insertBefore() not working properly with PHP DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I've got this structure:

```
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

and I want to rearrange elements with PHP DOM to turn it into something like this:

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

I tried doing this with the following code:

```
$html = "<p>Second paragraph</p><p>First paragraph</p><p>Third paragraph</p>";

$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(1)->insertBefore($dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0));
```

However when I use:

```
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I get:

```
First paragraphSecond paragraph
```

as a result, so I guess I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php):

```
public DOMNode DOMNode::insertBefore ( DOMNode $newnode [, DOMNode $refnode ] )

refnode
    The reference node. If not supplied, newnode is appended to the children.
```

Therefore since you are not specifying the reference node it is appending it to the children. Your code will produce this HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>First paragraph<p>Second paragraph</p></p>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What you need to do is do the `insertBefore` on the `parentNode`, in reference to the Second Paragraph like so:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$nodes->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore($nodes->item(1), $nodes->item(0));
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I echo all document it works: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kib-yn1

Comment: It "works" but it does not produce valid HTML at all.